# Textfield in panel in frame is initially set to NOT visible; later the program sets it to visible but it doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, gui-builder

The text in `txDiv0` is supposed to show up when division by 0 is attempled. It is set to NOT visible initially. The code works correctly BUT THE TEXT ONLY SHOWS WHEN I click the frame border as if to make it larger. Making the frame literally **one pixel taller** makes the field show up.

Code produced by GUIbuilder:

```
    private javax.swing.JTextField txDiv0;
...
    txDiv0 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
...
    txDiv0.setText("Division by 0 is undefined");  
...
    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
    jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
    jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(txDiv0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 300, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
      jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(0, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(txDiv0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
...    
    pack();
```

And here's how I try to make it show up:

```
    txDiv0.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println();
```

(The println is there to show me that the code DID execute.)

The textfield NEVER shows up unless I barely wiggle an edge of the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the **container** that holds your txDiv0 component after changing its visibility. The reason for this is:

- `revalidate()` tells the component to have its layout managers re-layout the components it contains. This laying out will cascade through all the layout managers of the components that the current container holds.
- `repaint()` suggests to the JVM that the container may have some dirty regions that need to be repainted after components have been removed, added, or shifted around.

As an aside, I strongly urge you to lay the GUI-builder to the side when learning a GUI library, and instead try to create and modify the GUI by hand as this will give you a greater understanding of the underpinnings of the GUI library and will force you to read and study tutorials more.

Comment: --DUDE! I was watching an old TV Monty Python's Flying Circus this morning and found a Hungarian trying to get some matches from a tobacconist! So never mind about "Snakes on a Plane"!!

Comment: Geez... got so excited I forgot--***THANKS, AGAIN!!!*** YOU ROCK!! It of course worked.

Comment: Criminey... I gotta wait 7 minutes to vote yours as "accepted answer". Hope I remember!

Comment: Two days ago, I couldn't have agreed more with laying aside GUIbuilder, but with GUIBuilder's help and in two days I created a fairly-robust GUI that is a complex number mathematics calculator--e.g., it'll find the sine of (3 + 4i) and also find all 6 of that number's 6th roots. (I already had the calculation routines from June or July.) I learned SO MUCH that I'm now on the GUIbuilder bandwagon! There is NO WAY I could've done that GUI in two days without GUIbuilder. And in fact the experience has sent me back to an old project that I abandoned since I had no clue what I was doing with swing.